# tkinter/python How i can transfer text from one frame to other using tkinter using python

Tags: python, tkinter, frames

I am not able to send the same data from one frame to other by click on the button
tkinter/python How I can transfer text from one frame to other using tkinter using python can I send my text from `tbox2` to `tbox1`with button.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root, width=1000, height=1000)
frame.pack()

tbox1 = Text(frame)
tbox1.place(x=0, y=0, height=400, width=600)

tbox2 = Text(frame)
tbox2.place(x=0, y=400, height=1000, width=1000)


tbox3 = Text(frame)
tbox3.place(x=500, y=0, height=400, width=500)
button1 = Button(frame, text='Check', width="20", height="3", font='helvetica 20', bg="green",
                            command=lambda: set(tbox1))
button1.place(x=700, y=700, height=30, width=100)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

`set()` does not work like this. You only use `set()` with specific widgets or tkinter variables like `StringVar()`.

You can use `get()` and `insert()` to move data between text fields.

add this function above your button.

```
def copy_data():
    tbox2.delete(1.0, 'end')
    tbox2.insert(1.0, tbox1.get(1.0, 'end-1c'))
```

And change your button to this:

```
Button(frame, text='Check', width="20", height="3", font='helvetica 20', bg="green",
       command=copy_data).place(x=700, y=700, height=30, width=100)
```

Comment: thank u sir it work properly

Comment: sir in this code if i want to get fetch file from back-end and import that file into tbox1 frame using keywords how can i use that